# Re-expressing $\mathbb{R}^{kd}$ as the union of $k!$ sets, obtainable one from the other by permutation

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, euclidean-geometry

This question may be trivial, but anyway, I have some troubles in visualizing the answer in a geometric way.

Let's start with an immediate example: let $u,v$ be distinct real numbers and let $\vec{x}_1=(u,v)$ and $\vec{x}_2=(v,u)$, then we could define a permutation map $\pi:\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\pi(\vec{x}_1)=\vec{x}_2$ and we could cover $\mathbb{R}^2$ with two subsets $V_1$ and $V_2$, such that $\vec{x}_1 \in V_1$, $\vec{x}_2 \in V_2$ and, more generally, $\pi(V_1)=V_2$. It suffices to consider the two sub-regions of $\mathbb{R^2}$ separated by the diagonal line (included in both the sets).

Now, let $u_1, \ldots, u_k$ be elements of $\mathbb{R}^d$, all differing in at least one component, and consider the following vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{dk}$: $\vec{x}_1=(u_1, \ldots, u_k)$ and the vectors $x_2,\ldots, x_{k!}$ obtained by permuting the $d$-dimensional blocks $u_1, \ldots, u_k$. E.g., we could have
$
\vec{x}_2=(u_2, \ldots, u_k, u_1).
$
Clearly, for each $\vec{x}_i$, $i=2, \ldots, k!$, there exists a permutation map $\pi_i: \mathbb{R}^{dk}\mapsto \mathbb{R}^{dk}$ such that $\pi_i(\vec{x}_i)=\vec{x}_1$.

**Question**: can we conclude that there is a cover of $\mathbb{R}^{kd}$ consisting in $k!$ subsets $\Theta_i$ such that, for $i=1, \ldots, k!$, $\Theta_i \cap\{\vec{x}_1, \ldots, \vec{x}_{k!}\}=\{\vec{x}_i\}$ and $\Theta_1=\pi_i(\Theta_i)$?

**Edit:** note that, using partial orders, of course one could cover $\mathbb{R}^{dk}$ with $(k!)^d$ sets $\Theta_i$ complying with the property that $\Theta_1=\pi_i(\Theta_i)$, for a suitable permutation $\pi_i$. However, for some of them $\Theta_i \cap \{\vec{x}_1, \ldots, \vec{x}_k\}=\emptyset$!